# Querying a XML Document in SQL

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I've got the following snipped of code from a rather large XML file i'm working on:

```
<Product id="4161" removed="false">
    <NativeReviewStatistics>
        <AverageRatingValues>
            <AverageRatingValue>
                <AverageRating>3.0</AverageRating>
                <RatingDimension>
                    <ExternalId>Quality</ExternalId>
                    <RatingRange>5</RatingRange>
                </RatingDimension>
            </AverageRatingValue>
            <AverageRatingValue>
                <AverageRating>4.0</AverageRating>
                <RatingDimension>
                    <ExternalId>Value</ExternalId>
                    <RatingRange>5</RatingRange>
                </RatingDimension>
            </AverageRatingValue>
        </AverageRatingValues>
    </NativeReviewStatistics>
</Product>
```

I'm looking to get an end result with rows that look like the following:

```
ProductId | ExternalId | AveRating | RatingRange
4161        Quality      3.0         5
4161        Value        4.0         5
```

So far I've got this:

```
    SELECT  feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS ProductId
    FROM    @xmlData.nodes('/Feed/Product') feed ( product )
```

But I'm a little stumped as to where to go from here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS ProductId,
    step3.data.value('ExternalId[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ExternalId,
    step2.data.value('AverageRating[1]', 'decimal(10,1)') AS AveRating,
    step3.data.value('RatingRange[1]', 'int') AS RatingRange
FROM
    @xmlData.nodes('/Feed/Product') feed ( product )
CROSS APPLY
    feed.product.nodes('NativeReviewStatistics/AverageRatingValues/AverageRatingValue') step2(data)
CROSS APPLY    
    step2.data.nodes('RatingDimension')  step3(data)
```